# How to add a filter with a list and a comma separated field in EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.1, on the database side I have a comma separated list field (ex: "love,travel") and a function that receives a list of string, now I need a filter using the list of string over the comma separated field, I have been trying different approaches by on run-time I'm getting some exceptions, basically the linq to entities does not support the filter.

Table:

```
public class Image
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string Tags { get; private set; }
}
```

I have been trying something like:

```
var multiple = request.Tags.Split(new[] { ',' }).ToList();

images = images.Where(c => multiple.Contains(c.Tags));

images.Where(c => multiple.Any(t => c.Tags.Split(new[] { ',' }).ToList().Contains(t)));

images.Where(c => request.Tags.All(tag => ("," + c.Tags + ",").Contains("," + tag + ",")));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should modify the database and class model to make this work. Introduce a `Tag` entity having a many-to-many relationship with `Image`.

Comment: Thank you Gert, this is one idea that i have, but I want to be sure if is the query possible with the current database model.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I chose the solution provide by Gert, so basically I splitted the table adding an ImageTag table.